# Add a click event on carousel previous and next buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel, slick.js

I want to write a function that triggers on the click of next and previous buttons of slick carousel. The problem I am facing is that, it is not in sync with the slide change.
If I click on the next and previous arrows very fast, then even though the click event gets fired that many times but the slide change is not as per the no. of clicks.

For example:
If I click the next arrow 6 times very fast, then the slide shown should be slide no. 6. But this is not happening.

```
$('.my-carousel').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    draggable: false,
    swipe: false,
    arrows: true,
    fade: true
});
$('.my-carousel').on('click','.slick-next', function(){         
    console.log('next');
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Please share the code you have or better yet make a working snippet that shows the problem you have or create a https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Why do you want to add a click event manually to the arrows ?
I mean Slick it self ads the click event as long as you are enabling the flag arrows in settings